# What does the dollar syntax mean in a Rust format string?

Tags: rust, string-formatting

I'm going through Rust by Example and the use of `$` (the dollar sign) [in this example](https://rustbyexample.com/hello/print.html) isn't clear to me:

```
// You can right-align text with a specified width. This will output
// "     1". 5 white spaces and a "1".
println!("{number:>width$}", number=1, width=6);

// You can pad numbers with extra zeroes. This will output "000001".
println!("{number:>0width$}", number=1, width=6);
```

I found this in [the documentation for `std::fmt`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/index.html), but it doesn't clarify things for me:

```
format_string := <text> [ maybe-format <text> ] *
maybe-format := '{' '{' | '}' '}' | <format>
format := '{' [ argument ] [ ':' format_spec ] '}'
argument := integer | identifier

format_spec := [[fill]align][sign]['#']['0'][width]['.' precision][type]
fill := character
align := '<' | '^' | '>'
sign := '+' | '-'
width := count
precision := count | '*'
type := identifier | ''
count := parameter | integer
parameter := argument '$'
```

Poking around at the code a bit, I've found that it doesn't compile without the dollar sign, but "`width`" can be replaced with any arbitrary identifier. i.e. the following is equivalent to the third line in the first code block:

```
println!("{number:>test$}", number=1, test=6);
```

Answer (score 7):

It allows the width or precision of another formatted item to be provided as an argument instead of hard-coded as part of the format string. The parameter can be specified using a numeric index or a name.

[The documentation says](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/index.html#width):

> The value for the width can also be provided as a [`usize`] in the list of
>   parameters by using the dollar syntax indicating that the second argument is
>   a [`usize`] specifying the width, for example:
>
> ```
> // All of these print "Hello x    !"
> println!("Hello {:5}!", "x");
> println!("Hello {:1$}!", "x", 5);
> println!("Hello {1:0$}!", 5, "x");
> println!("Hello {:width$}!", "x", width = 5);
> ```
>
> Referring to an argument with the dollar syntax does not affect the "next
>   argument" counter, so it's usually a good idea to refer to arguments by
>   position, or use named arguments.

It [also says](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/index.html#precision):

> There are three possible ways to specify the desired `precision`:
>
> [...]
>
> 2. An integer or name followed by dollar sign `.N$`:
>
>    use format *argument* `N` (which must be a `usize`) as the precision.
>
> [...]
>
> For example, the following calls all print the same thing `Hello x is 0.01000`:
>
> ```
> // Hello {arg 0 ("x")} is {arg 1 (0.01) with precision specified inline (5)}
> println!("Hello {0} is {1:.5}", "x", 0.01);
>
> // Hello {arg 1 ("x")} is {arg 2 (0.01) with precision specified in arg 0 (5)}
> println!("Hello {1} is {2:.0$}", 5, "x", 0.01);
>
> // Hello {arg 0 ("x")} is {arg 2 (0.01) with precision specified in arg 1 (5)}
> println!("Hello {0} is {2:.1$}", "x", 5, 0.01);
>
> // Hello {next arg ("x")} is {second of next two args (0.01) with precision
> //                          specified in first of next two args (5)}
> println!("Hello {} is {:.*}",    "x", 5, 0.01);
>
> // Hello {next arg ("x")} is {arg 2 (0.01) with precision
> //                          specified in its predecessor (5)}
> println!("Hello {} is {2:.*}",   "x", 5, 0.01);
>
> // Hello {next arg ("x")} is {arg "number" (0.01) with precision specified
> //                          in arg "prec" (5)}
> println!("Hello {} is {number:.prec$}", "x", prec = 5, number = 0.01);
> ```

Comment: I had read through that documentation but a couple of things still escape me. Firstly, does the compiler infer that `myValue$` is specifying the width because it's a numeric value not preceded by a period? Secondly, why does `println!("{number:0>#width$}", number=-19, width=6);` print `000-19` whereas `println!("{number:#>0width$}", number=-19, width=6);` prints `-00019` and `println!("{number:#>width$}", number=-19, width=6);` prints `###-19`? Thanks!

Comment: @Fred *does the compiler infer* — there's no inference here; you are specifying that `myValue` is the width by using `$`. *000-19* — you are filling it out to 6 characters using `0` to fill, without regard to the sign. *-00019* — you are padding out to 6 characters with regard to the sign (the `#` means nothing in these cases). *###-19* — you are filling it out to 6 characters using `#` to fill, without regard to the sign.

Comment: I think I've figured it out. I now see that in `0>` the `0` is the `fill` character, whereas in `>0` the `0` is the `['0']` `format_spec`. However I believe `$` marks the argument for a parameter, as described in the specs thusly: `parameter := argument '$'`. It could be width but it could also be precision as in your example: `{number:.prec$}`.